# Convert input string to a clean, readable and browser acceptable route data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Scenario:

There is a title called "AJAX, JSON & HTML5! The future of web?"
Would like to convert this into this "ajax-json-html5-the-future-of-web"

Basically what I need is a function that strips out all the non alphabets and then replace them with a single hyphen and lowercase that.

Problem:

With some effort I could do that with `String.Replace` or `String.CharAt` but I think thats all too messy. Am I correct? I believe Regex is the way to go. As my Regex is very rusty I am unable to get something that shows the desired output.:)
Disclaimer: This is basically a Give me the Codez. But I have pretty much covered my options I guess.

Comment: You are talking about a [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example using Regex - this should get you in the right direction (Edit - added clearing off the trailing dash so it looks nicer)

```
    var input = "This is some amazing Rexex Stuff!";
            input = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\W]+", "-").ToLower();
            input = Regex.Replace(input, @"[-]+$", "");
            Console.Write(input);
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: +1: double slashes is also a concern :) but can i do something like another regex.replace like the ones we use when changing multiple spaces to a single space?

Comment: Thanks for the catch :)  Added it in

Comment: @naveen - current version squares away double dashes and trailing dashes so you should be set unless I missed something...

Comment: also what if i would like to enforce a max length limit. could you show that too if its possible in this solution. i am ok with the subString method for that. just to know if its possible here?

Comment: Assuming you wanted a max of 30 caracters, post conversion but before you clip off the last dash, use code like "if (input.Length > 30) input = input.Substring(0, 30);" - works a treat.  (tbh normally I have an extension method for string that wraps up a version of substring that does not blow up if the source string is too short)

Comment: @Bob: exactly. I also have an extension method for the same. i have a bool field to indicate whether to append three dots after that :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I used to this a while back, it's not perfect but it should get you started:

EDIT: Still ugly but output is better: `ajax-json-html5-the-future-of-web-`

```
string title = "AJAX, JSON & HTML5! The future of web?";

title = Regex.Replace(title, @"&amp;|&", "-");

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < title.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(title[i]) || char.IsDigit(title[i]))
        builder.Append(title[i]);
    else
        builder.Append('-');
}
string result = builder.ToString().ToLower();
result = Regex.Replace(result, "-+", "-");
```

Comment: +1: thank you for this. this definitely look good. let me work with it for a while.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` should be used in this case.