# StackOverflow like URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-301, redirect

Its my understanding that the questions in StackOverflow has the following format

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/{question-id}/{slug-made-from-question-title}
```

So basically the question is retrieved using the question-id. so whatever value I give the slug is  immaterial.

First I would like to know whether this understanding is wrong :)

I have a URL

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291678/convert-input-string-to-a-clean-readable-and-browser-acceptable-route-data
```

Then I changed the slug manually like this.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291678/naveen
```

But it changed to the original slug. Firebug showed me a permenant redirect 301 on the altered URL. How to implement this functionality?

Comment: for a minute there I thought this was a meta question :-)

Comment: @Jodrell: to me, SO in itself is a wonderful book on how to build a site. I always put it as my benchmark :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `Response.RedirectPermanent` available since ASP.NET 4.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        string id = RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
        string passedSlug = RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
        //get the original slug from database / dymanic method
        string originalSlug = GetSlugFromID(id);

        if(!originalSlug.Equals(passedSlug))
        {
            var url = String.Format("~/test/{0}/{1}", id, originalSlug);
            Response.RedirectPermanent(url, true);
        }
    }
}
```

On an unrelated side note, would like to think Stack Overflow is not saving the slug at database. Its created dynamically from title [using something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291678/convert-input-string-to-a-clean-readable-and-browser-acceptable-route-data/6291788#6291788). I just altered the title of my question and the slug changed. It will be un-necessary to store the slug in database as it is redundant to title.

Comment: +1 i have edited your answer a bit. otherwise i have to post my own answer. hope you don't mind.

Comment: @naveen: I welcome the edit, it clearly provides a more complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: how can i achieve this in MVC ? I mean how I can append the text after the ID ? I am using asp.net mvc

Answer (score 5):

This is done via [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) to the [preferred canonical URL](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139066). The script checks the requested URL to see if the URL matches the "preferred" version of the URL. If not, it sends a 301 redirect to the browser and tells it that the page has permanently moved to this location.

The reasons for doing this is fairly obvious: Without this, you can construct thousands of URLs like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291678/foo`, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291678/bar`, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291678/blah`; all pointing to same content. Search engines would penalize you for duplicate content.

## Edit

In your ASP.Net application you can compare the slug provided by the browser against the slug stored in the database. If they do not match, send a 301 redirect. You probably cannot do this via web.config or something else since database in involved. Here is example code I posted on my blog some time ago (not sure if it'll work):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myId As Integer = 1234
    Dim mySlug As String = "preferred-slug"
    If Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Equals("/" & myId & "/" & mySlug) = False Then
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://" & Request.Url.Host & "/" & myId & "/" & mySlug & Request.Url.Query)
        Response.End()
    End If
End Sub
```

I assume that you've already implemented some form of URL rewriting which throws any request for `/\d+/.+` to your asp.net page.

Comment: yep. i am curious on how to implement this in asp.net :)

Comment: I don't think you need to implement it, just configure it in IIS 7 (if you're running on Windows Server 2008).

Comment: @Roy you can't know the right slug until you check the database. So you can't configure some static rule on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either **IIS URL Rewriting** or **ASP.NET Routing**

Check this article for detailed comparison: 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/