# friendly url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow like URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292205/stackoverflow-like-url-routing)

I have a question that is not addressed.

As I can redirect to a url friendly 404.php mistake is misspelled.

I want to keep ...

```
damain/news/1/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx

domain/news/1

domain/news/1/djfdkjfsdjffjss
```

Show the same page. When the only correct url is the first (`http://dominio.com/news/1/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx`) and if you write the second to third error404 redirect url.

Htaccess, with php, with canonical meta???

P.D: sorry for my writing. But I am Spanish and my English is not very something, I hope you understand the message

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292205/stackoverflow-like-url-routing/6292237#6292237

Comment: you don't need rewriting for that. just use an `ErrorDocument`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: @user1847844 la verdad no logro entender lo que buscas, por qué no me lo dices en español y vemos si te puedo responder. Un saludo :)